# How to disable Prelude Emacs and use system-wide Emacs

Tags: spacemacs, prelude

I have installed Prelude Emacs by using `wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/raw/master/utils/installer.sh -O - | sh`. I am using Debian and  new to Emacs. Now whenever I run emacs in terminal, it opens Prelude Emacs. I wonder it is possible to two versions of Emacs; one for system emacs (installed by `apt-get install emacs` ) and the other installed by the above command. I don't want to uninstall Prelude Emacs. But just having two different emacs. (This question could be asked for a different version emacs such as spacemacs which uses `.emacs.d` directory). So it will overwrite my configuration files inside `~/.emacs.d/` as Prelude did it for my system-wide Emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Prelude Emacs but you can launch emacs without any configuration file using `emacs -q` or with a special init file `emacs -q -l ~/.emacs.d/special-init.el`.

Maybe you want to create an alias e.g. `alias RawEmacs = 'emacs -q'`.

Comment: If I use new `init.el` file rather than defined one, this will load new packages from Melpa or will it borrow packages from `.emacs.d\elpa` directory?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test different setups in Emacs try using [Chemacs 2](https://github.com/plexus/chemacs2) is an Emacs profile switcher, it makes it easy to run multiple Emacs configurations side by side.

Move the configuration that you want to keep as your default to `~/.emacs.default/init.el`

Comment: Ive upvoted. And I use chemacs. But changeover is not entirely trivial. All paths like `~/.emacs.d/...` need to be changed to use `expand-file-name`